# How to implement multi device log in?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, authentication

My app allows registered users to log in.

My current implementation to log in a user, is to register a `sessionid` on the server's DB and on the mobile device itself. If these 2 match, they are authenticated and logged in.

However this poses a problem when a user has multiple devices (iphone, android, tablets etc). Because unless they are logged out from their previous session, the server's DB will retain their current session and prevent they from logging in from other devices.

Hope someone can share their solution to handle multi device log ins.

Comment: It's not my area, but how about -- when you recognize the same credentials again -- distribute the same session id?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. But their sessionid is hashed on the server. I've no idea what their actual session id is.

Comment: You don't control the server?  I think then you're stuck with the server's policy.

Comment: Actually I do. We have full control. Just saying the session id stored on the server is hashed. Maybe there's no need to hash a sessionid? The reason it's hashed is because I thought of it like a password. So no one can impersonate a user if they somehow managed to get the sessionid from the server. If that makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense, the server is distributing a hashed token.  You would distribute the same one to the second login.  I think it should be okay as long as nothing client-specific is in the hash.

Comment: Hm. Problem is the session id generated is random and unique. Since the value stored in DB is hashed, I couldn't think of how I can issue the same session id (unhashed) when the user logs in from another device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51054/discussion-between-danh-and-resting)

Comment: This was an interesting discussion.  Did it end up working for you?  I think gmail must keep per-device sessions as it even gives you the option to log out on all the devices.  When you did logout did you simply destroy the cookie from the app or did you change something on the server?